# Spring boot with Spring framework 3.1.1

Tags: spring-boot

Is Spring boot  support  spring framework 3.1.1?.The reason is I need to deploy external project JAR(which is developed in Spring3 and hibernate3 ) with Spring boot project.Please help me.Is it possible?

Comment: Did you actually try?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's too old.

[Spring 1.x is now deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019) and that [supported Spring 4.3.23](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v1.5.20.RELEASE).